# Python, anticipating an endless loop

Tags: python, time, infinite-loop

I have code that can potentially have an endless loop. I would like to be able to stop this in code, is there somethng that can do that? Some thing like:

```
for i to range(0,5):
    timer = on
    run(x)
    #while run is running 
    if timer.time > 30:
        exit run(x)
        print("out of time ")
    print(timer.time)
```

So the output could be: 3, 2, out of time 30, 2, out of time 30

I'm afraid this might require threading, which I have attempted in C and Java, for school, but never python.

Comment: You mean like [break](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)?

Comment: No, because I don't want to break out of the for loop, just that iteration's run(x)

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: it's clearly pseudocode.

Comment: But python is pseudocode. If you're going to ask a question about python, why not use python? At least the intent would be clearer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, fixed it a bit hope that helps

Comment: Can your `run()` function execute independently of the others? Do they rely on any global state? If not, you can run them on separate processes/threads and manage that.

Comment: ...by the way, doing true general-case infinite-loop detection is impossible. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options:

1. If you can modify `run`'s "endless" loop, make it check for the time. This is probably the easiest.
2. If on Linux/UNIX, you can use `signal.alarm` with a `SIGALRM` handler to get interrupted after a fixed period of time.
3. You can spawn a separate thread and [kill the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) when time elapses. This is rather nasty, and should only be used if you're on Windows (or care about portability) and have no way to modify `run`.
4. You could spawn `run` into a separate process and kill the process when time expires (e.g. with `multiprocessing`).

Here's an example of interrupting a calculation using `signal.alarm`:

```
import signal

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass

def alarm_handler(*args):
    raise TimeoutException()

def tryrun(func, timeout=30):
    oldhandler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
    try:
        signal.alarm(timeout)
        func()
    except TimeoutException:
        print "Timeout"
    else:
        print "Success"
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0) # disarm alarm
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, oldhandler)

import time
tryrun(lambda: time.sleep(10), 5) # prints Timeout
tryrun(lambda: time.sleep(2), 5)  # prints Success
```

Comment: I'm working on a mac so I imagine signal.alarm might work, but I have never seen that before. Can you give me a psudeocode example please? Is this the sort of thing you're talking about? http://pguides.net/python-tutorial/python-timeout-a-function/

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: yes, that's basically it. The code I've posted is very similar, except that it resets the alarm within the `try` to avoid race conditions.